# Where are S/PDIF connectors on an MSI A58M-E35 motherboard?

Tags: motherboard, spdif

I've checked MSI site and nothing about them there. Checked all the blogs and still nothing.
Trying to connect a Gigabyte GeForce 9800GT video card to Motherboard. Has a 2 pin cable but can't figure where it goes on the board.

Comment: The motherboard might not have the connector if the product specification says nothing about it then it doesn't have it and the cable will be unused

Comment: *"I've checked MSI site..."* -- The one authoritative source that should be checked (and you don't mention it) is the User Manual for the motherboard.

Comment: I thought it would have been obvious that most people (I do anyway) would go to the User Manual first, website second and check the board out with a magnifying glass third. Seems logical to me.

Answer (score 3):

From what I can see that motherboard does not implement S/PDIF audio; evidenced by the lack of a S/PDIF (or *any* digital) output on the back panel (just has three 3.5mm "phone" jacks), and the fact that the manual and specs on MSI's site make no mention of S/PDIF.

[image: MSI A58M-E35 rear I/O panel]

Since there's no digital audio output supported, the connector you're looking for will not exist.

Comment: *"That motherboard does not implement S/PDIF audio; evidenced by the lack of a S/PDIF (or any digital) output on the back panel"*  -- The back panel is not the sole location for a S/PDIF port.  I have a (popular ASUS)  mobo with a 3-pin header on the mobo that outputs the S/PDIF signal (one of the pins is +5VDC to power a TOSLINK port which I did attach).

Comment: @Sawdust It's evidence, not absolute proof. ;)  A more absolute proof would probably be along the lines of the on-board header missing; which is kind of the crux of the OPs question. :)

Comment: *" It's evidence, not absolute proof."* -- Yet you make the absolute statement *"That motherboard does not implement S/PDIF audio;"*.

Comment: @Sawdust As humans, we can make statements without providing all possible evidence.  Doesn't mean those statements are right, but they can still be made.  Regardless, I softened it up a bit for you.  If you have absolute proof of it either way, or feel my answer needs further tweaking, please feel free to submit an edit (or a whole new answer).

Comment: @sawdust That's what you're supposed to do. You cite conclusions and you provide evidence that supports them. Do you think one needs absolute proof to make absolute statements? If so, that's utterly ridiculous. That would mean that I can't say "My wife had a bad day at work today" unless I had *absolute* *proof* she had a bad day at work, which is comically absurd.

Comment: Apparently neither of you have read "Stranger in a Strange Land" about a Fair Witness.  From that simple concept I have tried to separate what I know from what I assume.  The original answer is flawed as I pointed out, and the revisions are appropriate.  @DavidSchwartz your example is a subjective statement, but the actual case is objective.  Your failure to make that distinction reflects poorly on you. Yes, you do need absolute proof to make absolute (non-subjective) statements.  Otherwise they should be qualified or be  called "generalizations".  BTW your use of *"cite"*.makes no sense

Comment: @sawdust The argument would be the same if it was "My wife had tacos for lunch today", which is objective. And you are utterly and totally wrong about what you need to make unqualified statements. If you are right, everyone else is using language wrong most of the time they say they "know" something or assert propositions. And everyone can't be wrong in how they use language -- by definition, the outlier is improper.

Comment: What happened to focussing on the answer to my question vs all this arguing? Thank you Sawdust. "The back panel is not the sole location for a S/PDIF port".

Comment: I checked the whole board with a magnifying glass for any pin that had any reference to S/PDIF. I can't find one. Damn!

Comment: Just looked at a tutorial on Hardware Secrets and it has a picture of a JSPDIF1 connector (3 pins). I didn't look for something with such a long name. http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/article/600/2 Back to the magnifying glass - again.